# Socket.IO jsonp polling opening new tabs in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, socket.io, salesforce

I'm tasked with maintaining an app that runs in Salesforce, is served by a node server and uses Socket.IO to communicate back to the node server. Everything was working fine until recently.

Now periodically (once every week or two) our Socket.IO drops down to jsonp polling and rather than just making the calls opens the jsonp polling url in a new tab. So far we only have reports of this happening in Chrome.

This doesn't start with any user action, in fact many times it occurs while the user is on different browser tab.

Any ideas where I can look to try to understand why this is happening?

Comment: I never did get to the bottom of this. We just removed jsonp polling from options available to Socket.IO. Socket.IO should have never been used in that spot and I would have just ripped it out entirely if we weren't planning to kill that product all together.